# Adjust line-height of multi-lined span in a div

Tags: css, html

What I need is as:

1. the line height between blue lines is 5px.

2. the line height between blue, black and brown line is 20 px.

 Please see the code I have tried. I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.divClass{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

.divclass span{
 line-height: 5px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divClass">
<span style="color:blue;">first abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span><br>
<span>second efgh</span><br>
<span style="color:brown;">third hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Line height of 5px will make your text overlap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having `line-height: 5px` will make your text overlap, so I guess you want each line 5px far from each other. To do so, you need to make `line-height` 5px greater than `font-size`. The "line height between blue black and brown" is called `margin` (you can also use `padding`) and in order to work ,you have to set `display: block` to `span` tags

```css
.divClass{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
}

span { display: block; }

.blue{
  color: blue;
 line-height: 20px; 
}

.brown { color: brown; }

.black, .brown, .blue {margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
  <span class="blue">first abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
  <span class="black">second efgh</span>
  <span class="brown">third hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
          .divClass{
              overflow-y: auto;
              width: 100%;
              height:100%;
              line-height: 20px; 
          }

          .span-blue{
               line-height: 5px !important; 
           }

           .span-other{
               line-height: 20px !important; 
            }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="divClass">
          <span style="color:blue;" class="span-blue">first 
             abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
             abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span><br>
         <span class="span-other">second efgh</span><br>
         <span style="color:brown;" class="span-other">third 
            hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider commenting your code instead of providing just code

Comment: this is simple code doesn't need any comment I think.

Comment: what is the meaning of OP and SO.?

Comment: OP = Original Poster. SO = StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
**HTML:**

```
<style>
.divClass{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

#blue{
    line-height: 5px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divClass">
<div id="blue" style="color:blue;">first abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz <br>abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div><br>
<span>second efgh</span><br>
<span style="color:brown;">third hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this is what you need. Inspect the elements to check if it is proper line height.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Yuri fro guiding me. Your answer helped me solve the issue. Still, I would like to post my resolved code with minimal changes. Please find the corrected code below. Thanks all.

Corrections done: Replaced span with div and added margin-bottom instead of line-height with new values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.divClass{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

.divclass div {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divClass">
<div style="color:blue;">first abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div><br>
<div>second efgh</div><br>
<div style="color:brown;">third hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have applied `line-height: 5px;` to `.divclass span`

> You have to specify for which span you want this particular CSS
>   when there are multiple spans available in this div.

For this, you can use `span:first-child` or add class to that particular span.

I have used `span:first-child` here.

```css
span:first-child{
  line-height: 5px; 
}

span{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
<span style="color:blue;">first abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span><br>
<span>second efgh</span><br>
<span style="color:brown;">third hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)